# Targeting and wrapping the 3rd digit after a decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make a script that will wrap only the 3rd digit following a decimal point. The purpose is to format fractions of a cent for oil prices.

ie. 3.249 entered would output

```
    3.24<sup>9</sup>
```

What I have so far wraps anything following the decimal. For instance I can span the 1st, the first 2 or all 3, but cant ignore the first 2 and span only the 3rd.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html(
        $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html().replace(/\.\d{3}/,
            function(a){
                return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
        })
    );
});
</script>
```

I need the regular expression /.\d{3}/ to either select the last digit or 3rd decimal place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alanfleming/wDntk/

Comment: since others have already given an answer, will throw an fyi about your original effort as a comment: `{3}` is a quantifier; a range. You are telling it to match for 3 of the preceding char (the `\d`), not the third `\d`.  So the solutions provided show that you must first match for the first 2 digits, and then match for the 3rd digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you want a couple of capture groups:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html(
        $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html().replace(/(\.\d\d)(\d+)/g, "$1<sup>$2</sup>");
    );
});
</script>
```

That matches a dot followed by two digits followed by one or more digits. It captures the first part (the dot followed by two digits) and the second part (one or more subsequent digits) in two separate capture groups. In the replacement, we replace the overall match with the first capture group unchanged followed by the second one wrapped in the `sup` tag markup.

You also don't need to pass a function as the second arg (although doing so is just fine), you can just use the `$1`, `$2`, etc. placeholders.

If you *want* to use a function, capture groups are passed to the function as additional arguments after the full match:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html(
        $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html().replace(/(\.\d\d)(\d+)/g, function(m, c1, c2) {
            return c1 + "<sup>" + c2 + "</sup>";
        });
    );
});
</script>
```

---

Just for completeness: You don't **need** to use capture groups, but it's probably cleanest. You can do this without if you continue using a function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html(
        $('.pricesup .maintext > span').html().replace(/\.\d{3,}/g, function(m) {
            return m.substring(0, 3) + "<sup>" + m.substring(3) + "</sup>";
        });
    );
});
</script>
```

The rex matches a dot followed by three *or more* digits, and then chops the matching string up.

I'd go with the first solution above, FWIW, using the capture groups and placeholders.